# how to change font size of Google Chart Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, tooltip

How do i change the font size Google Chart Tooltip?
[ This is what i tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Albion87/ujpv8oep/3/ ]
These are the set options that i have ..

```
// Set chart options
var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    tooltip: { textStyle: { fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 7 } },       
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    chart: {
        title: 'Year-by-year coffee consumption',
        subtitle: 'This data is not real'
    },      
    vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        }
    },
    legend: { position: 'left', alignment: 'start' },
    series: {
        2: {
            targetAxisIndex: 1
        },
        3: {
            targetAxisIndex: 1
        }
    },
    backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
    chartArea: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Lj9.png)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is *material* chart...

there are several options that simply do not work with *material* charts,
including...

```
tooltip.isHtml
tooltip.showColorCode
tooltip.textStyle
tooltip.trigger
```

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

recommend trying *core* chart with following option...

```
theme: 'material'
```

---

*material* chart --> `google.charts.Bar` -- `packages: ['bar']`

*core* chart --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the "theme" WhiteHat! Indeed, Google still hasn't made Material charts mature enough.